# Jinja2 filters: from a dictionary list to a json object list

Tags: python, jinja2

My code goes like this:

```
...
{% for person in persons %}
<div>{{ person.name }}</div>
<div>{{ person.relatives | map(attribute='__dict__') | map('tojson') | list }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The result is just weird:

```
[Markup('{"affinity": "mother", "name": "mary"}'), Markup('{"affinity": "father"}'), ...]
```

Why am I getting this `Markup` wrapper and how do I get rid of it?

I am also open to rewrite this, I am just interested in getting the proper json result. I tried a few alternatives with no success and I think this is the closer I got.

Comment: Why don't you just convert it in python and just show the converted JSON file?

Comment: Yep crossed my mind, and will be my last resort if this doesn't get an answer.

Comment: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#utilities says _**class jinja2.Markup([string])** A string that is ready to be safely inserted into an HTML or XML document, either because it was escaped or because it was marked safe._ Have you tried looping on that list and displaying each and every element? That should end up making them render properly.

Answer (score 0):

The filter `tojson` is not relevant for the desired result:

```
...
{{ person.relatives | map(attribute='__dict__') | list }}
...
```

Result:

```
[{'affinity': 'mother', 'name': 'mary'}, ...]
```

**Extra**:

To put it inside a `data` tag element:

```
{% for person in persons %}
<div data-relatives="{{ person.relatives | map(attribute='__dict__') | list | replace('\'','\"') }}">{{ person.name }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, one can stringify the `json` object in python (i.e. before rendering the view). But just proving here that the same result can be achieved in `jinja2`.